# Rails edit action is getting too big

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my current rails application , there are multiple tabs for the edit action. All tabs go to the same action. For example if i modify some input field in one tab , all the tabs parameters go to edit action.I need to send only those modified. Is there any suggestion for this scenario

Comment: Look into http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute.

Comment: Can you share your code snippet here ? It's really vague to tell anything with above description

Comment: My intention is to update only input fields which are changed... ie only pass paramters whose input field changes....by default rails passes all paramters into update action..i want to limit to only few which have changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track your model changes using `.changed?` method 
example code:

```
user = User.last
user.changed?  #=> false
```

**for a specific attribute you can use**

```
user.name_changed? #=> true
```

it's s part of
 [Rails Dirty Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)